How to build an Avro Pojo record with a map of value type array?
Someone at my organization tried to get fancy and declared this Avro schema:
{
  "type": "record",
  "name": "ASillySchema",
  "namespace": "com.my.company.redacted",
  "fields": [
    {
      "name": "my_overly_complex_map",
      "type": [
        "null",
        {
          "type": "map",
          "values": [
            "null",
            "string",
            "boolean",
            "int",
            "long",
            "float",
            "double",
            {
              "type": "array",
              "items": [
                "null",
                "string",
                "boolean",
                "int",
                "long",
                "float",
                "double"
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      ],
      "default": null
    }
  ]
}


I am trying to add tests to a Java Kafka Streams app that consumes from this topic. I can't figure out how to build up a message with a map field with an entry of type array. Here is what I've naively tried:
Map<CharSequence, Object> myOverlyComplexMap = new HashMap<>();
List<Object> mixedTypeObjectArray = Arrays.asList(
                null,
                "a string",
                true,
                35,
                20L,
                201f,
                202d
);
myOverlyComplexMap.put("arrayKey", mixedTypeObjectArray);
ASillySchema testRecord = ASillySchema.newBuilder()
                             .setMyOverlyComplexMap(myOverlyComplexMap)
                             .build();       

// send testRecord to topic using Java kafka producer...

I end up with this error:
Caused by: org.apache.avro.UnresolvedUnionException: Not in union ["null","string","boolean","int","long","float","double"]: [null, a string, true, 35, 20, 201.0, 202.0]
    at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericData.resolveUnion(GenericData.java:896)
    at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumWriter.resolveUnion(GenericDatumWriter.java:272)
    at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumWriter.writeWithoutConversion(GenericDatumWriter.java:143)
    at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumWriter.write(GenericDatumWriter.java:83)
    at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumWriter.writeMap(GenericDatumWriter.java:305)
    at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumWriter.writeWithoutConversion(GenericDatumWriter.java:140)
...

Does anyone know how to build up this Java object I'm trying to send?

The array doesn't need all of the types, it only can have one of those types.

This is valid Avro... I'm able to register it to the schema registry and I'm also able to produce sample messages (with an array of values of mixed types) via kafka-avro-console-producer. So I'm not quite sure what you mean by "it only can have one of those types."

I never said it wasn't valid schema. I was saying that the payload was invalid. The array can only have one type of object, not the exact list of types in the schema. As the answer below says, the array must only have one primitive type. Thus why you get "Unresolved union"

I see now. Sorry for the confusion. So just to be clear, you are saying there actually isn't a way to do what I'm trying to do in Java?

Your schema is valid, but none of the array items are unions, so it's the schema that's the issue not Java. And as mentioned, the number/order of array content does not need to be the exact same as the schema

The map in the schema can hold several types of primitive values, and an array of primitive values. It cannot hold an array of arrays.
To fix, drop the nested list in your code.

Hey - there's no array of arrays. It's a map with array as a valid value type. The schema registers just fine to the schema registry and I'm also able to produce sample messages with a map containing an array via kafka-avro-console-producer.

new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList creates a mutable list, not a nested list

Confusing on my behalf... new ArrayList() is not necessary here. I've removed it. But yeah, as @OneCricketeer said, it does not create a nested list.

You're both right.  However, the error message says the list is matched against the array item union. Not the map value union. So any fix is related to that.
